# CD Command in C++ command line

Tags: c++, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make a `CD` command for a shell I call POSH (Pine's own shell).

If the previous `cd` command didn't end in a `/`, it will append the two paths and throw (`cd pine` then `cd src` will error because path would be `/home/dingus/pinesrc` instead of `/home/dingus/pine/src`).

I know why this happens, but can't seem to fix it.

Here is the source code:

```cpp
inline void cd(string cmd)
{
    if(cmd.length() < 3) return;
    string arg = cmd.substr(3);
    if(fs::is_directory(fs::status( string(path).append(arg))))
    {
        path.append(arg);
    }
    else cout << "Error: \"" << arg << "\" is not a directory" << endl;
}
```

Comment: How much harm is there in appending the slash if no slash is present?

Comment: Why are you not using `std::fs::path`? It would handle path concatenation for you. Or is that your own `fs`?

Comment: [operator /=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) is probably closest to what you want.

Comment: @Quimby I'm not sure how to use it by looking at docs, how might I use `fs::path`?

Comment: When `path` is `"/home/dingus/pine"` and `arg` is `"src"`, why would you expect `string(path).append(arg)` to result in `"/home/dingus/pine/src"` instead of `"/home/dingus/pinesrc"`? Keep in mind The Golden Rule Of C++ Programming: your C++ program always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do.

Comment: @RamdomlyRandom If your `path` variable is  `fs::path p="/";` then to get to `/home/foo/bar.txt`, you can need to just write `p / "foo" / "bar.txt"`. In your `if` I would use `p / arg` and inside the body `p/=arg;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string(path).append(arg)` is performing string concatenation. You are not appending any of your own slashes between filesystem elements. So, if the `path` is `/home/dingus/`, then `cd pine` would just append `pine` to the end producing `/home/dingus/pine`, and then `cd src` would just append `src` to the end producing `/home/dingus/pinesrc`, as you observed.

You would need to do something more like this instead:

```cpp
string curr_path;

inline void cd(string cmd)
{
    if (cmd.length() < 4) return;
    string arg = cmd.substr(3);
    string new_path = curr_path;
    if ((!new_path.empty()) && (new_path.back() != '\\')) {
        new_path += '\\';
    }
    new_path += arg;
    if (fs::is_directory(fs::status(new_path))) {
        curr_path = new_path;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error: \"" << arg << "\" is not a directory" << endl;
    }
}
```

However, since you are using the `<filesystem>` library anyway, you should be using `std::filesystem::path` (especially since `std::filesystem::status()` only accepts `std::filesystem::path` to begin with). Let the library handle any path concatenations for you, eg:

```cpp
fs::path curr_path;

inline void cd(string cmd)
{
    if (cmd.length() < 4) return;
    string arg = cmd.substr(3);
    fs::path new_path = curr_path / arg;
    if (fs::is_directory(new_path)) {
        curr_path = new_path;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error: \"" << arg << "\" is not a directory" << endl;
    }
}
```

`std::filesystem::path` implements [`operator/`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash) to insert a slash if one is not already present.

Comment: Is ``fs::path = path / arg;`` supposed to be ``fs::path new_path = path / arg;``?

Comment: @RamdomlyRandom yes. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: ``error: no match for ‘operator/’`` on this line: ``fs::path new_path = path / arg;``

Comment: @RamdomlyRandom [works fine for me](https://godbolt.org/z/YdfGxWEjq). Did you declare `path` as being `fs::path` or `std::string`?

Comment: oh right. thank you!